# Adding +1 to integer value

Tags: c#

I cannot think of what i'm doing wrong here, the code is very simple, i'm trying to increment an intenger by +1 everytime a button is pressed, instead of doing for example: 5 + 1 which is 6, the label prints 51.

Code:

```
        // update count here...
        lblCount.Text = lblCount.Text + 1;
```

The label holds the initial value, i thought just adding what the label was currently then just doing **+1** would be enough but it's not working as i thought.

any helpwould be appreciated.

Comment: That code should not compile at all! Or am I missing something??

Comment: @NisargShah I think the code would compile just fine, only problem is OP incrementing a `char` instead of an `int`.

Comment: @samAlvin - He's not incrementing a char. He's concatenating to a String.

Comment: @NisargShah - The + operator when at least one argument is a String means concatenate (I think you know) and will convert the other param to String automatically if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to int and then convert to String

```
  var total =  int.Parse(lblCount.Text) + 1;
  lblCount.Text = total.ToString();
```

Comment: And then convert to string?

Comment: @NisargShah yeah

Answer (score 2):

Yeah that is because output of `label.Text` is a `String` use it like this

```
int x = Int32.Parse(lblCount.Text);
```

Then add `x + 1`

Answer (score 1):

This will increment when conversion is successful. 
In **C# 7** code:

```
        if (int.TryParse(lblCount.Text, out int currentValue))
        {
            var result = currentValue + 1;
            lblCount.Text = result.ToString();
        };

        if (int.TryParse(lblCount.Text, out int currentValue))
        {
            currentValue += currentValue 1;
            lblCount.Text = currentValue.ToString();
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

`lblCount.Text` holds a text in it(better to say String) and now your are trying to make arithmatic calculation with integer.
It at first holds it's value and add the next value as a string(like concatination). To avoid this,
First you have to convert it to integer before adding the 1.
you do that like this `lblCount.Text =  int.Parse(lblCount.Text) + 1;`

Answer (score 0):

As you already notice your problem is that current value saved as a string. So you can not do mathematical operation on a string.

Instead of parsing string to integer every time you want add 1 - save current value in local variable of type integer and do all operations on this variable.

```
private int count;

// update count here...
count = count + 1;
lblCount.Text = count.ToString();
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 int counter; 
 public void Yourbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    counter + 1;
    lblCount.Text =counter.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: `counter` would need to be initialized, and `counter + 1` will not change the value of `counter`. You could put `counter++` instead, after setting it to the int value of `lblCount.Text`.